# Method to output Messagebox messages

Tags: c#

Is there a better way to present the following method which prints out different messages depending on the parameters. Find it too wordy and lengthy and yet unable to simply it cos the messages differ at each line. Do advice if I could shorten it. Thank you.

```
private void message(int choice, string result)
{
    if (choice == 1 && result == "Draw")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("It is a draw. Both chose Rock");
    }
    else if (choice == 2 && result == "Draw")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("It is a draw. Both chose Paper");
    }
    else if (choice == 3 && result == "Draw")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("It is a draw. Both chose Scissor"); 
    }

    else if (choice == 1 && result == "Win")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Congratulations! Rock beats Scissor");
    }
    else if (choice == 2 && result == "Win")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Congratulations! Paper beats Rock");
    }
    else if (choice == 3 && result == "Win")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Congratulations! Scissor beats Paper");
    }

    else if (choice == 1 && result == "Lose")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You lose. Paper beats rock");
    }
    else if (choice == 2 && result == "Lose")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You lose. Scissor beats Paper");
    }
    else if (choice == 3 && result == "Lose")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You lose. Rock beats Scissor");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are looking for [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont know if this is a good idea but you can do like this:

```
private void message(int choice, string result)
        {
           if(result == "Draw")
           {
            switch (choice)
            case 1: MessageBox.Show("It is a draw. Both chose Rock");
            break;
            case 2: MessageBox.Show("It is a draw. Both chose Paper");
            break;
            case 3: MessageBox.Show("It is a draw. Both chose Scissor");
            break;
           }
           //similarly do for the rest.
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Setup an enum to represent the possible choices:

```
public enum Choice
{
    Rock = 1,
    Paper = 2,
    Scissor = 3
}
```

Then just use `string.Format()`:

```
var selectedChoice = Enum.GetName(typeof(Choice), choice);

var beatsChoice = selectedChoice == Choice.Rock ? Choice.Scissor
                    : (selectedChoice == Choice.Paper ? Choice.Rock : Choice.Paper);

if (result == "Draw")
    MessageBox.Show(string.Concat("It is a draw. Both chose ", selectedChoice);
else if (result == "Win")
    MessageBox.Show(string.Concat("Congratulations! ", selectedChoice, " beats ", beatsChoice);
else if (result == "Lose")
    MessageBox.Show(string.Concat("You lose. ", selectedChoice, " beats ", beatsChoice);
```

Comment: Probably adding the `Description` attribute for each enum member would be a good idea.

Comment: How do you know that "Rock beats ..." and not vice-versa? How do you know that rock was chosen at all?

Comment: This doesn't include the opponents choice. You have hard coded the "x beats..."

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I like your design, but given what you have this is (slightly) nicer to maintain ...

```
private void message(int choice, string result)
{
   string self;
   switch(choice)
   {
     case 1: self = "Rock"; break;
     case 2: self = "Paper"; break;
     case 3: self = "Scissor"; break;
   }

   switch(result)
   {
     case "Draw":
       MessageBox.Show(String.Format("It is a draw. Both chose {0}", self));
       break;

     case "Win":
       string beats;
       switch(choice)
       {
         case 1: beats = "Scissor"; break;
         case 2: beats = "Rock"; break;
         case 3: beats = "Paper"; break;
       }
       MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Congratulations! {0} beats {1}", self, beats));
       break;

     case "Lose":
       string loses;
       switch(choice)
       {
         case 1: loses = "Paper"; break;
         case 2: loses = "Scissor"; break;
         case 3: loses = "Rock"; break;
       }
       MessageBox.Show(String.Format("You lose. {1} beats {0}", self, loses));
       break;
       break;
   }
}
```

That said, this solution is still horribly ugly. A better way would to be passing around objects which encapsulate rock/paper/scissor states rather than "choice" ints. These would have methods to get what they beat. Printing would then be much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing is that you could make the integer and string as Enum's this would allow you to print out the wording of the in very few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Use enums to increase readability. I would also use two parameters since it's not clear who won:

```
public enum RockPaperScissors
{ 
    Rock,
    Paper,
    Scissor
}

public enum GameResult
{ 
    PlayerOneWin,
    PlayerTwoWin,
    Draw
}
```

Then the method can be shortened to:

```
private void message(GameResult result, RockPaperScissors choice1, RockPaperScissors choice2)
{
    if (result == GameResult.Draw)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("It is a draw. Both chose " + choice1.ToString());                
    }
    else
    {
        string message = string.Format("Congratulations, {0} beats {1}!"
            , result == GameResult.PlayerOneWin ? choice1 : choice2
            , result == GameResult.PlayerOneWin ? choice2 : choice1);
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably the nicest so far, however the OP had slightly different messages for win vs loss cases, and this loses them.

Comment: @AndySavage: The messages can be modified as desired easily.